# How to create a child heading under parent heading in html table?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to make this template with html tables,

[image: Table]

This is my html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>data</td>
                    <td>data</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But it is not giving me the right format like the image above. How can i do it with table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the template as per the reference, you need to use this code

```css
table { border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse; }
table th { padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #000; }
table td { padding: 5px 10px; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Sr. No.</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Description of Goods</th>
        <th rowspan="2">HSN</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Qty.</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Unit</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Rate (per item)</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Total</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Discount</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Taxable Value</th>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">CGST</th>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">SGST</th>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">IGST</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amt.</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amt.</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amt.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called as Table with Irregular Headers

You have to use

```
<th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">MainHeadername</th>
```

for main Header and

```
 <th scope="col">SubHeaderName</th>
```

for Sub Headers

This Reference will be Helpful for further clarifications
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do this. You could use a table in a td or you could make use of colspan and rowspan like in my example.

Good luck.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Sr.No</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Description of Goods</td>
    <td rowspan=2>HSN</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Qty.</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Unit</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Rate(per item)</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Total</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Discount</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Taxable value</td>

    <td colspan=2>CGST</td>
    <td colspan=2>SGST</td>
    <td colspan=2>IGST</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>Amt.</td>
    
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>Amt.</td>
    
    <td>Rate</td>
    <td>Amt.</td>    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using colspan:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>65</th> 
    <th>80</th>
    <th colspan="2">40</th> 
    <th colspan="2">20</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th>Men</th> 
    <th>Women</th>
    <th>Men</th>
    <th>Women</th>
    <th>Men</th>
    <th>Women</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td>82</td> 
    <td>85</td>
    <td>78</td>
    <td>82</td>
    <td>77</td>
    <td>81</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```